# Length of the rule (twocolumn)

Tags: two-column, rules

When `\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]` is declared, is there a way to change the size of the vertical rule created by LaTeX? (I need to increase it)

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add to your question a minimal, complete document producing the output of the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to redefine `\@outputdblcol` (from the LaTeX kernel) to let the rule have some depth; the following example shows this redefinition (signaled with `%NEW`); I used a depth equal to `2ex`, but you can use any other value; of course, this modification will apply to all the document:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\setlength\columnseprule{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@outputdblcol{%
\if@firstcolumn
\global \@firstcolumnfalse
\global \setbox\@leftcolumn \box\@outputbox
\else
\global \@firstcolumntrue
\setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
\hb@xt@\textwidth {%
\hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
\box\@leftcolumn \hss}%
\hfil
{\normalcolor\vrule \@depth2ex \@width\columnseprule}%NEW (original without \@depth2ex)
\hfil
\hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
\box\@outputbox \hss}%
}%
}%
\@combinedblfloats
\@outputpage
\begingroup
\@dblfloatplacement
\@startdblcolumn
\@startdblcolumn.
\@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi
{\@outputpage
\@startdblcolumn}%
\endgroup
\fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

A fragment of the bottom part of the first page showing the extension:

[image]

With the help of the `etoolbox` package, the code reduces to (using now a `3ex` depth):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\setlength\columnseprule{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@outputdblcol}{\vrule \@width\columnseprule}{\vrule \@depth3ex \@width\columnseprule}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The second way is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user13596: Then you must click the green check mark, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you use the multicol package which allows you to set  \columnseprule to the desired width.  Additionally the multicol package allows you to change the number of columns at any point in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\newpage
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But your answer doesn't change the length of the vertical rule and this seems to be what the OP wants to do. Also, `\columnseprule` can be changed without `multicol`.

Comment: Exactly! I want to change de length, not the thickness.

My code is about 1500 lines, because it depends of a lot of code involving conditionals. Is it reasonable put it here?